# Sas breaking a string into words to find similiar phrases by number of common words between phrases

Tags: sas

Ideally I am trying to find similiar phrases. I have two phrases in a dataset about max 5-6 words in each. I used the Fuzzy matches of complev, compged etc. Since it is mostly string matching sometimes I could not achieve what I could match just by reading the phrases. The phrases dont have misspelling but sometimes Shorten words like Replacement to replace etc and rearranging of words eg: Electric Component keyboard replacement and keyboard inward component replace. Like the below example:

```
 DATA COMPONENT;
 infile datalines delimiter=','; 
 length FIRST $ 1000 FIRST_B $ 1000;
 INPUT FIRST $ FIRST_B $;
 DATALINES;
Electric Component keyboard replacement, Keyboard inward component replace
Electric Component keyboard replacement, Monitor Component Replacement
Electric Component keyboard replacement, Mouse component
Electric Component keyboard replacement, Wire Replacement
Electric Component keyboard replacement, PIN part
;

 DATA Compged;
 SET COMPONENT;
 CALL COMPCOST('SWAP=', 5, 'P=', 0, 'INS=', 10,'DEL=',10,'APPEND=',5);
 First_COMPGED=COMPGED(FIRST, FIRST_B, 'iln');
 RUN;

 PROC SORT DATA= Compged;
 BY  First_COMPGED;
 RUN;
```

Since this alone did not match I thought use another factor of trying to find the same words being used as another factor. Thus want to split to words and compare. how many common words appear and add this as an additional factor.

```
 /* Tried this approach*/

proc iml;
s = "Introduction,to SAS/IML... programming!";
delims = ' ,.!'; 
n = countw(s, delims);  
 words = scan(s, 1:n, delims);  /* pass parameter vector: create vector of 
 words */
 print words;
```

Not sure how to implement this in the current table to get words and words_b from the phrases first and first_b.
Please suggest if there is any other way to achieve it for the above example?

Comment: what is the output you want to achieve

Comment: You can use a cross join to check, but these types of checks can be computationally intensive. You can search with 'fuzzy matching' on Google, Communities.sas.com or lexjansen.com for many options and examples.

Comment: @Kiran I am looking for Electric Component keyboard replacement, Keyboard Inward component replace with the lowest score suggesting best match